# how to make a build (gwt + jsf 2.0 + spring), jboss

Tags: java, spring, gwt, maven, jboss7.x

What I am trying to do is to create 2 projects that depend on a third project like:

1. GWT Project - for my admin interface
2. JSF 2 Project - for my frontend interface
3. Spring - for business logic

What do you I have to do? How do I create these projects using maven and when I run package to package my GWT, JSF, Spring projects and then add them into an ear?

- GWT - war
- JSF - war
- Spring - jar (where I will use spring-data to get things from database)

**What do I have to have? 2 maven modules and 1 maven project? which are the maven modules? which is the maven project?**

How can I write a build (I don't know in what - `ant` or `maven`) to archive all these projects (in an `ear`) and deploy it on `jboss`? is it the right way?

Is it possible to run all these projects directly in `jboss` from `eclipse`? so that I don't have to remake the build and deploy every time I change something?

- Should I use maven?
- What should I use to have my projects clean?
- Should I use `ant` and `maven`? isn't it possible only with `maven`?
- What is the exact process that should happen when I want to do a deploy?

**EDITED**

1. I created 1 maven project ProjectEAR
2. I created 1 maven module using a [GWT archetype](http://mojo.codehaus.org/gwt-maven-plugin/)
3. I created 1 maven module using a spring-data archetype

I added the 2 `modules` as dependencies to my `maven project` and then I added a build as `ear` using `maven-ear-plugin` like this:

```
<plugin>
    <artifactId>maven-ear-plugin</artifactId>
    <version>2.8</version>
    <configuration>
        <finalName>project</finalName>
        <version>5</version>
        <generatedDescriptorLocation>${basedir}/src/main/application/META-INF</generatedDescriptorLocation>
        <modules>
            <javaModule>
                <groupId>ro.myproject</groupId>
                <artifactId>business-logic</artifactId>
                <bundleFileName>busineeLogic.jar</bundleFileName>
            </javaModule>
            <webModule>
                <groupId>ro.myproject</groupId>
                <artifactId>admin</artifactId>
                <bundleFileName>admin.war</bundleFileName>
                <contextRoot>/admin</contextRoot>
            </webModule>
        </modules>
    </configuration>
</plugin>
```

But now, when I deploy my `ear` in `jboss-as-7.1.1` my `admin.war` inside the `ear` is not correctly deployed.. it's not extracting the generated GWT folder...

[image: deployment details]

And because of this my `GWT application` is not loading correctly => it's not working because my `*.nocache.js` is located in that folder...

What can I do now? did I do something wrong?

Comment: does the GWT admin interface depend on parts of the business logic? Or is it working "standalone" and just using the same database? Will all 3 modules use the same version when released or do you expect a different lifecycle for them?

Comment: it's using some parts of the business logic.. when I modify the business logic I will modify the interface if I have to

Comment: @wemu can you please answer as "answer" and can you, please, give more details about the structure.. which one is module, which one project and how will I deploy my application. is it easier with eclipse? (or it has nothing to do with eclipse) .. I would like to accept your answer

Comment: What you need is to setup a *Maven* project in an IDE of your choice (NetBeans/Eclipse/ IntelliJ IDEA, etc.). Just google it and there are definitely many tutorials on how to set up a sample project. But Maven is about management of dependencies related to your project and your build tool.

Comment: @skuntsel I know about maven but I know that I can package my applications pretty easy.. and I would prefer that way.. I just don't know what structure I need in ear and how will they be referenced

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Normally you would have a parent project, and underneath 4 child projects:

1. GWT
2. JSF
3. common (your business logic)
4. EAR

GWT and JSF depend on common. EAR depends and GWT and JSF

Comment: I understand.. but how do I build my app? GWT requires a special build type.. it has to convert the java into javascript

Comment: I would suggest the same structure. One parent pom.xml and these 4 modules. For GWT there is a maven plugin http://mojo.codehaus.org/gwt-maven-plugin/ so you can use the standard maven process.

Comment: And the transitive dependencies would be included automatically for you (something your project dependencies rely on).

Answer (score 0):

I edited my post with a solution, it works this way.

The problem I encountered is that I added the `EAR application` to JBOSS using `eclipse` but `eclipse` is not adding the `ear` but is creating a project of it's own... but if I deploy the ear in `jboss` manually it's working.. took me a few hours to realise that...